# Проблема с python и django

Tags: python, django

Всем приветики. Недавно я переустановила винду, и у меня слетели все программы. Пришлось заново ставить python и django. Но появилась проблемка, при вводе команды python в консоль, открывается Microsoft Store с предложением установить python, хотя даже интерактивная консоль с питоном есть. А при попытке скачать django вылетает такая ошибка

( WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.), а потом пишет что django успешно установлен.

И естественно при попытке использовать django пишет что не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Помогите, не знаю что делать...

Answer (score 1):

Предупреждение говорит о том, что надо добавить папку C:\Users\me\AppData\...\Python37\Scripts в PATH:

1. В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск: Система (Панель управления)
2. Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
3. Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды PATH. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
4. В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH. Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.

https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Ничего не поменялось. Тем более в окне Изменение системной среды не имеется значение PATH...